# Angular singlton service been created mutiple times

Tags: angular

My application has several modules. See below. StoreService is provided by AssetModule which is imported by the other two services.

- AssetModule

  - StoreService (Injectable, provided by the module)
- DashboardModule

  - AssetModule and StoreService reference
- MapModule

  - AssetModule and StoreService reference

Whenever we route to these modules using the routing config below, StoreService is created each time. Even though StoreService is a singleton. If we lazy load these modules, the problem gets worse, where StoreService is created every time we route to that module. When a new one is created OnDestroy is not called as well. So if we register to observables/emiters, events fire for all out-of-use instances of StoreService.

How do we avoid this kind of behavior?

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => DashboardModule,
    canActivate: [LoginAllRoutesGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'asset',
    loadChildren: () => AssetModule,
    canActivate: [LoginAllRoutesGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'map',
    loadChildren: () => MapModule,
    canActivate: [LoginAllRoutesGuard]
  },
```

Comment: You should refer to the official docs [here](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services). If you provide the service in your module, it will be instantiated per instance of that particular module. As per docs, if you want it to be singleton, you should inject that service only in the root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the easer way is defined the service providedIn in root

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class StoreService {

}
```

Really I don't know if you can providedIn `AssetModule` makes singleton

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'AssetModule',
})
```

Comment: @Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
}) did not work, I tried it before. It still behaves the same

Comment: @Patola, if you declare in providers of one module a service, this service is only singleton in this module. If you use providedIn in a service you **not** declare in the providers of the modules.